# Javascript using For loop for false

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm learning now for loops, and as an example I was given in a game this (with '.result-paras' being p classes):

```html
        <div class="form">
            <label for="guess-field">Enter a guess: </label>
            <input type="text" id="guess-field" class="guess-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guess-submit">
        </div>

        <div class="result-paras">
            <p class="guesses"></p>
            <p class="last-result"></p>
            <p class="low-or-high"></p>
        </div>
```

```
const resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.result-paras');
for (let i = 0 ; i < resetParas.length ; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
}
```

I want to try to copy it on an input type which I want to disable, meaning I want 2 input fields to be disabled using a loop and I'm having trouble getting it to work, would really appreciate your help:

```
const disableParas = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
for (let i = 0; i < disableParas ; i++ ) {
    disableParas[i].disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: @Andy - `i < 2`? OP wants to disable only 2 inputs. (which is a big ? :-) )

Comment: `i < disableParas.length`

Comment: When you copied the code, why did you drastically change the loop definition?  What was wrong with just copying it as-is and changing the variable names accordingly?

Comment: html markup would be useful here

Comment: @Andy The fields seem to still be disabled when I run this code

Comment: @troubledcoder: When I run the code snippet in the question, none of the form inputs are disabled...

Answer (score 0):

When using a `for` loop to iterate over a list like that, you often use it like this, counting up a variable up to the length of the list:

```
const disableParas = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
for (let i = 0 ; i < disableParas.length; i++ ) {
    disableParas[i].disabled = false;
}
```

The first part of the for loop is what you do initially, the second part is the condition to stop the loop and the last part is executed each iteration of the loop.

Comment: The fields seem to still be disabled when I run this code

Comment: @troubledcoder: Then please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Because the JavaScript code itself [demonstrably works](https://jsfiddle.net/zfw58k6o/).